# smoothley animate a span to fit its text with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have created a hangman game that each letter is in a span.

**HTML**

```
<span class="letter">A</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.letter{
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

after the puzzle is solved I want to move letters beside each other to form the word, I also need to resize the span to fit its text (that is one letter) to avoid extra spaces. removing the class that contains height and width results to what I need but the problem is that I want to do this smoothly.

Comment: please post the complete HTML, specially to display the initial position of the letters from which they need to move beside each other.

Comment: I have no problem with moving them, consider as a single separate span with position absolute, my problem is with resizing it to its text. just leave the moving and help me with resizing.

Comment: ok so you don't have a monospaced font for the aplha's and the issue is that, when you move them beside each other; one can observe irregular space between the aplha's. Is that a right guess?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G8RJ7/

Comment: yes, actually the language i'm using is not english (its persian, just like arabic) the letters join each other (imagine it like hand writing) and the irregular space is more effective than english)

Comment: some people when they don't have solution for the question. just easily vote down the question and pass.

Comment: Hi Ashkan I'd love to see the game, Put up a link when its ready.

Comment: Sure. I had created a website for fun now it has become the first in its field in Iran, the game is a small part of the website (a website that you can find meaning of the names) that people can invite others and challenge them too play. this a way I have thought of bringing more visitors to my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone the element, set the clone width to `auto` and measure the width. Then remove it, and animate the original to that width.

Something like this:

```
$('span.letter').each(function(){
    var temp = $(this).clone();
    $('body').append(temp);
    temp.css('width', 'auto');
    var newWidth = temp.width();
    temp.remove();
    $(this).animate('width', newWidth);
});
```

Comment: I will need lots of changes in your code to fit mine as there are other issues too. but I got the Idea of how it should be done, and this was all I needed. thanks a lot.

Comment: قابلی (I used Google Translate!)

Comment: many thanks. as you have used the translation tool it show how much you care, thanks for you kindness. Iran's formal language is Persian but I'm one of the 52% turks which lives in Iran ;)